# Cassandra Hadoop Integration and Wordcount Example

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, integration, word-count

I am using Cassandra 1.1.6 and Hadoop 1.0.4. I tried to integrate them and run worcount example in cassandra. I know by default this example uses some jars in it. However, I want to run this example with hadoop. For now, I am using master and only one slave. What modificications do I need to do in order to run this example with hadoop?

Comment: Which client are you using, Hector or CQL?

Answer (score 0):

I set this up once and documented what I did here

http://blog.alvazan.com/165/how-to-set-up-the-cassandra-wordcount-example/

it could be out of date.  We will be doing another example with PlayOrm for cassandra eventually as well with it's NoSql entities (uses nosql patterns instead of relational patterns though with some relational ones).

Dean